# Update CSV file on Google Drive to be used on Data Studio with PyDrive

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, pydrive

I need to update a CSV file located on my Drive because I use it on a dashboard in Google Data Studio.
Until now, I was using this code :

```
previous_GDS_df = pd.read_excel(path_to_GDS_file)
pd.concat(objs=[previous_GDS_df, df_GDS]).to_excel(path_to_GDS_file, index=False)
f = drive.CreateFile({'id': spreadsheet_id})
f.SetContentFile(path_to_GDS_file)
f.Upload()
```

On which :

- "previous_GDS_df" is the content of the CSV file I'm updating,
- ""path_to_GDS_file" the path to my local CSV file, on which I do the modifications,
- "df_GDS" the df of my modifications, the elements I'd like to append to my file on Drive.

Basically, my theory was the following :
"I extract the previous content of the file, I append to it the new content then I edit my Drive file with 'SetContentFile' and I upload it all."

The problem is that when I edit my file on Drive, I need to reconnect everytime my file in my dashboard GDS because I think that SetContentFile erase entirely the previous file Drive to write a new one. In this case, I must reconnect the Drive file to GDS because it was deleted and rewrited.

So, I'm looking for a solution to update my Drive file so I will not have to reconnect everytime my file to the dahsboard and the modifications will appear magically.

Do you have a solution ? My theory is surely bad. I'm missing something somewhere.

Thank you for your help, ask me if more information is needed.

--- EDIT ---
I've tested some solutions but nothing worked. The best solution i tested was this one (thanks to the helps in the comments) :

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.

def getCreds(): # Authentication
    
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    
    return creds


def updateFile(service, spreadsheet_id, path_to_GDS_file): # Call the API
    media = MediaFileUpload(path_to_GDS_file, mimetype='application/vnd.google-apps.spSreadsheet', resumable=True)
    res = service.files().update(fileId=spreadsheet_id,media_body=media,fields="*").execute()
    return res

def main(spreadsheet_id, path_to_GDS_file):
    creds = getCreds()
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    updateFile(service, spreadsheet_id, path_to_GDS_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But the main() function doesn't just append to my csv file on GDrive, it rewrites the whole file so I have to reconnect on Data Studio.

Do you know how I could just append rows to my csv file located on the GDrive ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm thinking your current approach should work, as long as `spreadsheet_id` corresponds to the file you want to update. I don't know much about `pydrive` though. Would you be open to using the [official library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/index.html)? Updating a file is a question of calling [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update).

Comment: I think it's one of the solutions if I can't do it with pydrive. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `pydrive`, but in order to update a file via Drive API, you have to use [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update). This allows you either to just update file metadata, or also file content.

Here's a possible sample that uses the [official Python library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/index.html):

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
fileId = "DRIVE_FILE_ID" # Change to yours
filePath = "LOCAL_FILE_PATH" # Change to yours

def getCreds(): # Authentication
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds

def updateFile(service, fileId): # Call the API
    media = MediaFileUpload(filePath, mimetype='text/csv', resumable=True)
    res = service.files().update(fileId=fileId,media_body=media,fields="*").execute()
    return res

def main():
    creds = getCreds()
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    updateFile(service, fileId)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Note:

You'll first have to download your credentials file, as explained in the quickstart referenced below.

#### Reference:

- [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python)
- [service.files().update()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#update)

Comment: Thanks, I think your help get me closer to the solution, but the problem is still there. The main() function rewrite all of the file, it doesn't just append the rows to my csv file on Gdrive. Do you have a idea how to just append the new rows to my csv file?